# Phabricator SHH Config

Tags: linux, ssh, phabricator

I'm installing phabricator for code review.
I followed the Diffusion hosting repository guide and I can add new hosted repository.
But when I test the connection:
`echo {} | ssh -p 22 phassh@localhost conduit conduit.ping`
I got:
`Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).`

I used the debug mode of ssh
`sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator`
the log is:

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 321
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator len 321
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:6 setting AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/phassh/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:7 setting AuthorizedKeysCommandUser phassh
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:8 setting AllowUsers phassh
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:13 setting Port 22
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:14 setting Protocol 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:15 setting PermitRootLogin no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:16 setting AllowAgentForwarding no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:17 setting AllowTcpForwarding no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:18 setting PrintMotd no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:19 setting PrintLastLog no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:20 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:21 setting AuthorizedKeysFile none
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator:23 setting PidFile /var/run/sshd-phabricator.pid
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-f'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='/etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
```

I think my public key is not correct,but I don't know how to modified it.

My `/etc/passwd`:
`phassh:x:1000:1000:phabricator vcs-user:/usr/phassh:/bin/bash`

My `/etc/shadow`:
`phassh:NP:16882:0:99999:7:::`

My `/etc/sudoers`:
`phassh ALL=(root) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svnserve`

And another question is:
In the the Diffusion hosting repository guide says copy a publish key to `Settings > SSH Public Keys`,where the public key should are?

Comment: is that the output from /usr/sbin/sshd after you run your ssh command to try and connect? if so port 22 is never even being hit on your server.

Comment: @mschuett I have not connnected.Just run the command. I care that "Incorrect RSA1 identifier" so i think there is something wrong.

Comment: None of that matters at all. Try and make an actual connection and post the results.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this?

Comment: @PauloMatos No, I had given up.